# .Net 6 RemoteCertificateNameMismatch while calling AWS GetObjectAsync

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, .net-6.0

I am trying to retrieve a file in my S3 bucket using C#.

When I call GetObjectAsync, I get the RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error.
Ive tried to add:

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;`

to temporarily bypass with no luck. In my Program.cs class Ive also tried to add:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Client")
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                });
```

Both options do not work for me. Is there anything I should possibly try?

Comment: Any news here? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @Peter My issue was the my service url was incorrect. It should be https://s3.amazonaws.com. The error didn't help at all in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that the serviceUrl was incorrect when setting up the client, it should be https://s3.amazonaws.com